# OpenCV display image: window system doesn't support opengl

Tags: camera, opencv, c++

I have a project which uses the raspberry pi camera and openCV (also: ROS) to do some movement analysis. However, when I want to display the image (with the openCV API or a ROS node), there's an error saying

```
window system doesn't support opengl
```

And that happens although the openGL test-programs as well as raspistill work perfectly. I already tried installing openCV 2.7 from source and getting the ros-desktop packages, but nothing worked until now.

I'm using C++ to program everything, not python.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This worked for me http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/53911/10501

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raspberry Pi doesn't come with OpenGL support by default, but it's a simple installation. I believe you will just need to install `libgl1-mesa-dri`. You can do that at the command line using: 
Code:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri
```

Comment: Raspberry Pi doesn't come with OpenGL support - but it does have the version for embedded systems, i.e. OpenGL ES 2.0 which is similar but not the same... Also, according to Debian that says about the `libgl1-mesa-dri package`: "This [...] provides GLX and DRI capabilities: it is capable of both direct and indirect rendering. For direct rendering, it can use DRI modules from the libgl1-mesa-dri package to accelerate drawing. This package does not include the OpenGL library itself, only the DRI modules for accelerating direct rendering. "

Comment: this didn't work for me - even after reboot (Jessie)

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri
```

and reboot

Comment: Why? Your answer doesn't give any context, and while I know enough to check what it does, we can't assume that the user does, especially when the command contains `sudo`. Please elaborate.