# Python Face Recognizer Error

Tags: python, pi-2

[image]

I got this error during compilation.

Comment: Can you try setting your environment variable setenv DISPLAY host: 1 . Will this help?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you please try to make a picture snippet that focuses on the issue?

Comment: xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".

(Adding faces to traning set...:1401): GdkGLExt-WARNING **: Window system doesn't support OpenGL.

Comment: You should edit your question to include these details, not add them as comments.

Comment: i used ths code on raspberry "http://hanzratech.in/2015/02/03/face-recognition-using-opencv.html",and when I tried to execute it i got that error ,it must display some photo

Answer (score -1):

Possible your problem is like [OpenCV display image: window system doesn't support opengl](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40438/opencv-display-image-window-system-doesnt-support-opengl) here. Can you try installing `libgl1-mesa-dri`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri
```

Regards

Comment: I got the same error despite installing it :(