# GdkGLExt-WARNING **: Window system doesn't support OpenGL

Tags: raspbian, opencv, vnc

I have wrote a c++ program to display camera picture using opencv command `imshow`, worked perfectly on Wheezy. Lately I've updated my RPI to latest Jessie. Now I get the `GdkGLExt` error when running my program through a VNC client (direct connection doesn't have any problem).

On the raspberry forum suggested to installing `libgl1-mesa-swx11` and it worked, but when compiling get the following errors:

```
usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLU
```

Elsewhere suggested to installing `libgl1-mesa-dev` and `libglu1-mesa-dev`to resolve above errors, but installing these makes removing `libgl1-mesa-swx11`.

Any help appreciated (except downgrading to Wheezy:)).

Answer (score 2):

Despite the fact that direct connecting to RPI (hdmi interface) instead of `tightvnc` has no problem I came up using `x11vnc` and it worked like a charm. With x11vnc you have connecting to the main display interface, read further information and configuration in [Code Chief's Space](http://blog.tonywall.co/2013/07/setting-up-raspberry-pi-for-headless-mode-with-x11vnc/).

Note: if you have problem with your keyboard (like me) and your keyboard doesn't repeat when you hold a key then add `-repeat` argument to the x11vnc start-up file.